# SQL Take top and bottom elements from one column and put them in two different columns

Tags: sql, select, join

I have 2 select statements. I want to take the first name from alphabetical order and put it in a column titled First, and put it next to the last name in alphabetical order in a column titled Last.

```
SELECT Name AS 'First'
FROM contactlist
ORDER BY Name ASC
LIMIT 1;

SELECT Name AS 'Last'
FROM contactlist
ORDER BY Name DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need this, but here you go:

```
SELECT First, Last
FROM (
  SELECT Name AS 'First'
  FROM contactlist
  ORDER BY Name ASC
  LIMIT 1
  ) t, (
  SELECT Name AS 'Last'
  FROM contactlist
  ORDER BY Name DESC
  LIMIT 1
  ) t2
```

Might be a little more fun to take all your names and match them by row number (ASC First to DESC Last) -- something like this:

```
SELECT First, Last
FROM (
  SELECT Name AS 'First',
    @rowNum:=@rowNum + 1 rn
  FROM contactlist
    JOIN (SELECT @rowNum:= 0) r
  ORDER BY Name ASC
  ) t JOIN
 (
  SELECT Name AS 'Last',
    @rowNum2:=@rowNum2 + 1 rn
  FROM contactlist
    JOIN (SELECT @rowNum2:= 0) r
  ORDER BY Name DESC
  ) t2 ON t.rn = t2.rn
```

And some [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b33ea/1).